# My UIButtons get transformed to UIImageviews

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a `UIScrollview` of buttons and each time I click one of them i change its backgrund, image and label. It was working fine until today it crashes and it say unrecognized selector. When I `NSLog` my buttons i can see the second time the are not anymore buttons but `UIImageViews`.

How the hell can that happen ?

the code is very big but this is the problem part

```
for (int j = 100; j<[[Utils categoriesName] count]+100; j++)
{
    UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:j];
    UILabel *clickedLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:j+100];
    NSLog(@"%@  \n%@\n\n",clicked Button, clickedLabel);
    [clickedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[Utils categoriesIconLight] objectAtIndex:(j-100)]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickedButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[Utils categoriesIconLight] objectAtIndex:(j-100)]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [clickedLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [clickedButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"category-button-background"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [clickedButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"category-button-background-selected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [clickedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

the second time this loop is run clickedButton and clickedLabel are both UIImageViews

This is the first button and label on the first loop

```
<UIButton: 0xd981640; frame = (0 0; 269 46); opaque = NO; tag = 100; layer = <CALayer: 0xd981730>>  
<UILabel: 0xd9861c0; frame = (47 10; 222 22); text = 'Android'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 200; layer = <CALayer: 0xd985f10>>
```

and the second loop

```
 <UIImageView: 0xd983070; frame = (0 0; 160 120); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 100; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd974eb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd988660>>  
 <UIImageView: 0xd98c0a0; frame = (0 0; 160 120); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 200; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd98a5b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd98a3a0>>
```

Comment: can you paste code .whatever you done....

Comment: "How the hell can that happen ?" Are you sure you getting the same buttons each time through? (take a note of the address of the instance of the first button and label each time).

Comment: @trojanfoe  Yes I am more than sure. The tags are always 100 to 120 as you can see. Also my viewcontroller doesnt have a single UIImageView

Comment: Have you checked the instance values?  Please add the log output of the first two runs through this `for` loop.

Comment: you'd be better of using a `NSArray` to hold the buttons, and another to hold the labels. Most probably, the issue comes from bad tags.

Comment: @alex-i its been working for 2 months like this, this morning it crashed

Comment: you have `UIImageViews` with tag 100 and tag 200, you must be adding those somewhere. Using tags like this will get you in trouble sooner or later, and the code will only get harder to maintain.

Comment: @alex-i well there is not a single UIImageView in my UIViewController, let alone a UIImageView with a tag

Comment: Can you log the result of `self.view.subviews` once you get the crash (UIImageViews instead of the buttons)?

Comment: turns out the tags are overwritten by some UIImageViews but Im still searching where is this happening as i dont have any UIImageViews